# Use HTML Table as a datasource to bind data to Kendo UI Template

Tags: html, telerik, kendo-ui, datasource

I created a service that will return a set of HTML tables based on a request parameter. Currently, I return the data (HTML Page) back as a string. A sample output is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Person</h1>
      <table name="name">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#name</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Alfred Tucker</td>
            <td>Alfred Tucker</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="firstName">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#firstName</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Alfred</td>
            <td>Alfred</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="lastName">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#lastName</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Tucker</td>
            <td>Tucker</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="gender">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#gender</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#male</td>
            <td>male</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="birthYear">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#birthYear</td>
            <td>Birth Year</td>
            <td>1967</td>
            <td>1967</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="spouse">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#spouse</td>
            <td>Spouce</td>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#KymSmith</td>
            <td>Kym Smith</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="type">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="propertyID"> Property ID</th>
               <th data-field="property"> Property</th>
               <th data-field="valueID"> Value ID</th>
               <th data-field="value"> Value</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr>
            <td>http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys#Person</td>
            <td>Person</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now that I get the HTML string back, I would like to somehow bind each table to a Grid in the Kendo UI. How can this be done? If not, what would be the proper way to be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can just inject that HTML into your page (my example uses jQuery)

```
<div id="contentArea"></div>

$("#contentArea").html(serviceResult);
```

then turn all the tables into Kendo grids:

```
$("#contentArea table").kendoGrid({});
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I get classes and possibly other attributes set on the original rows and cells transferred to the new table? Kendo appears to replace them all, which means that information transported on the table markup itself is lost.